# Question about negative value using the ratio convergence test for integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, definition

> Find for what $p$, $\displaystyle \int ^{\infty}_0 x^p \arctan x dx$ converges.

By parts, it's equal to: $\displaystyle \lim_{b\to \infty}\frac 1 {p+1}x^{p+1}\arctan x |^b_0- \int ^b _0\frac {x^{p+1}}{(p+1)(1+x^2)}dx$

Now it's obvious that $p<-1$ because otherwise the left part outside of the integral goes to infinity.

So now we only have left to check for what $p$ this converges: $\displaystyle \int ^b _0\frac {x^{p+1}}{(p+1)(1+x^2)}dx$.

If we apply the ratio test with $g(x)=\frac {x^{p+1}}{x^2}$ I get that the limit $\displaystyle \lim _{x\to \infty}\frac {x^2}{(p+1)(1+x^2)}=\frac 1 {p+1}$.

Now here's the problem, since it has to be that $p<-1$, then $\frac 1 {p+1}<0$ and now what does it mean for the ratio test?

Since in absolute value it isn't zero or infinity then we have equvilience between $\frac {x^{p+1}}{(p+1)(1+x^2)}$ and $g$?

Comment: For $p\lt 1$ to be a problem, don't you actually have to have $p\lt -1$ so that $\frac 1{p+1}\lt 0$?

Comment: @abiessu yup, typo.

Comment: Just as a side note, this integral has a closed form: $$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{p}\arctan x dx = \frac{\pi}{2(p+1)\sin{\frac{\pi p}{2}}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integrand is non-negative, it suffices to verify finiteness:

$$
\text{For which $p$ is }\int_{\mathbb R^+}x^p\tan^{-1} x\ dx<\infty\text{?}
$$
Since $\tan^{-1}x=x+o(x)$, we have the bound $\tan^{-1}x\geq cx$ for $x\in [0,\epsilon)$. Thus $p$ must satisfy
$$
\int_{0}^{\epsilon}x^{p+1}<\infty,
$$
which means $p>-2$.

On the other hand, since $\tan^{-1}x \geq 1$ for $x>N$ we must have
$$
\int_{N}^{\infty}x^p<\infty,
$$
which means $p<-1$. Therefore $p\in (-2,-1)$.

To show that every $p$ in this range works, observe that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^+}x^p\tan^{-1}x\ dx\leq \int_{0}^{N}x^{p+1}+\int_{N}^{\infty}x^p\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}<\infty.
$$
We have used the bounds $\tan^{-1}x\leq x$ for $x\geq 0$ and $\tan^{-1}x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: What about $p=-10$? it will converge for that $p$, and why not just use the ratio test and show equivalence with $x^p$?

Comment: It doesn't converge when $p=-10$: think about what happens for $x$ close to $0$. The integral $\int_0^{0.1}x^{-10}\tan^{-1}x=\infty$.

Comment: OK, why does $\int_{0}^{\epsilon}x^{p+1}<\infty$ imply that $p>-2$?

Comment: When $p=-2$, the integral is $\log x$ which blows up to $\infty$ as $x\to 0$. When $p<-2$, the integral blows up to $\infty$ like $x^{p+2}$.